# Python: Reduce vs For loop vs built in functions

Tags: python, performance, functional-programming

newbie programmer here. Just started learning some functional programming and I was wondering what's going on behind the scenes in the various scenarios of reduce, a for loop, and built in functions. One thing I noticed when I calculated the times for running each of these was that using `reduce()` took the longest, the for loop inside the function took the second longest, and using a built in function `max()` took the shortest. Can somebody explain what's going on behind the scenes that causes these speed differences?

I defined the for loop as:

```
def f(iterable):
    j = next(iterable)
    for i in iterable:
    if i > j:
        j = i
    return j
```

and then compared it with

```
max(iterable)
```

and

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x if x>y else y, iterable)
```

and noticed, as stated previously, that using `reduce()` took the longest, the for loop inside the function took the second longest, and using a built in function `max()` took the shortest.

Comment: Probably lots of function calls. You can open the source code of reduce to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Python is an interpreted language. (At least, it's partly interpreted. Technically source code is compiled into byte code which is then interpreted.) Code running in an interpreter is almost always going to be a lot slower than native code running on the raw hardware of your machine.

But, a lot of the builtin functions and objects of Python are not written in the Python language itself. A function like `max` is implemented in C, so it can be pretty fast. It can be a lot faster than pure Python code that the interpreter needs to handle through.

Furthermore, some parts of pure Python code are faster than other parts. Function calls are notoriously slower than most other bits of code, so doing a lot of function calls is generally to be avoided if possible in performance-sensitive sections of your code.

So lets examine your three examples again with these performance thoughts in mind. The `max` function is implemented in C, so it's fastest. The pure-Python function is slower because its loop and comparisons all need to be interpreted, and while it contains several function calls, most of them are to builtin functions (like `next` which in turn calls `__next__` method of your iterator, both of which are likely builtins). The slowest example is the one using `reduce`, which, though it is builtin itself, keeps calling back out to the lambda function you gave it as an argument. The repeated function calls to the relatively slow lambda function are what make it the slowest of your three examples.

Note that none of these speed differences change the asymptotic performance of your code. All three of your examples are O(N) where N is the number of items in the iterable. And often asymptotic performance is a lot more important than raw per-item speed if you need your code to be able to scale up to a larger problem. If you were instead comparing a exponentially scaling algorithm with an alternative that was linear (or even polynomial), you'd see *vastly* different performance numbers once the input size got large enough. Of course it's also possible that you won't care about scalability, if you only need the code to work once for a relatively modest data set. But in that case, the performance differences between builtin functions and lambdas probably don't matter all that much either.

Comment: Super good answer! thanks for the feedback. I looked this question up a dozen other times and couldn't really understand the explanation but this was super clear.

Comment: One more question - how does max() then work under the surface, in C? What is python doing for the max() function? I looked at the C code and it doesn't make too much sense, do you have a simply way of explaining how it works in the interpreter?

Comment: The C implementation is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e9ac890c0273aee413aa528cc202c3efa29f1d7a/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1731), and it basically does the same kind of loop your pure-Python code does, just with the Python C API. A large part of the function is argument handling and error checking, the actual logic is pretty simple if you can identify it.